# Rails: current_user is nil in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to create a simple AJAX request to my ruby controller, but can not reach `current_user`.
The JS request:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('X-CSRF-Token', "P7qiN53QfDGbHjCXdV8BzL8McxgT1lBkXE3WpjP7taydWrF7d+xkZi+b9fG9TC13IMy61jmGK8pzhmdAoHjlZA==");
var myInit = { method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
};

fetch('/get_user_last_activities.json', myInit).then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    console.log(response);
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
});
```

I use the 'omniauth-twitter' and  'omniauth-facebook' gems.

The response tells that `current_user` is `nil` 
How can I teach my controller to access `current_user` when rendering .json responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your browser isn't sending the cookie with the fetch request. Try initializing like this:

```
var myInit = { 
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    credentials: 'same-origin'
};
```